# When closing my PWA the smartphone UI shrinks the webview into the Chrome icon rather than the PWA's icon... is this just my Android device?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

You know how app screens shrink back into their icons when you close them on an Android phone... well my PWA shrinks into the Chrome icon when I press the home button, and then the Chrome icon gets a notification symbol.  This is a really weird, non-native feeling experience.  Is this happening for other Android users?

I've done a bit of googling but couldn't find anything.

Comment: No, it's not normal. Have you tested other PWAs and got the same results? Have you tested your PWA on other devices?

Comment: @ArchNoob Same result for other PWAs but don't have easy access to other Android devices atm.  Think it must just be my Xiaomi phone's OS.

Comment: Mmh, What Android version are you using?

Comment: @ArchNoob Android version 8.0

Comment: I doubt if it's the phone's problem. Try going to https://pwa.rocks/ save one of the PWA on your home screen and observe if the issue persist.